# Prevent a user from adding the same task

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a todo list in javascript and I'm in the adding phase
tasks for the user. He wants to do so that if the user enters a task, he cannot enter it again

```js
const taskInput = document.getElementById('enter-task');
const addTaskBtn = document.querySelector('[data-submit-task]');
const toDoContainer = document.querySelector('[data-todo]');

addTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', addTask);
function addTask() {
    if (taskInput.value == '') {
        alert("Pole nie może być puste");
        return;
    }
    

    const taskContainer = document.createElement('div');

    taskContainer.classList.add('task-container');
    taskContainer.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" data-complete><p class="task-date">Data utworzenia: <span data-task-date>${getDate()}</span></p><div class="content-edit"><span data-task-title>${taskInput.value}</span><button type="button" data-edit>Edycja</button></div><button type="button" data-delete>X</button>`;

    

    const completeTaskBtn = taskContainer.querySelector('[data-complete]');
    const deleteTaskBtn = taskContainer.querySelector('[data-delete]');
    const editTaskBtn = taskContainer.querySelector('[data-edit]');

    completeTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', markAsDone);
    deleteTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
    editTaskBtn.addEventListener('click', editTask);

    toDoContainer.appendChild(taskContainer);
}
function markAsDone() {
    const taskTitle = this.parentNode.querySelector('[data-task-title]');
    if (this.checked) {
        taskTitle.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        return;
    }
    taskTitle.style.textDecoration = 'none';
}

function deleteTask() {
    toDoContainer.removeChild(this.parentNode);
}

function editTask() {
    const taskContainer = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (taskContainer.contains(taskContainer.querySelector('.task-edit-container'))) {
        alert("Nie możesz dodać więcej niż jednego pola do edycji");
        return;
    }

    const currentTaskTitle = this.previousElementSibling;

    const editTaskContainer = document.createElement('div');
    editTaskContainer.classList.add('task-edit-container');
    editTaskContainer.innerHTML = `<label>Wprowadź treść zadania</label><input type="text"><button type="button">OK</button>`;


    const submitTitleBtn = editTaskContainer.querySelector('button');       
    submitTitleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {       
        const newTitle = editTaskContainer.querySelector('input').value;
        if(newTitle == '') {
            alert("Pole do edycji nie może być puste");
            return;
        }

        const currentDate = document.querySelector('[data-task-date]');
        currentDate.innerHTML = `${getDate()}`;

        currentTaskTitle.innerHTML = newTitle;          
        taskContainer.removeChild(editTaskContainer);
    });

    taskContainer.appendChild(editTaskContainer);
}

function getDate() {
    let date = new Date();
    let day = date.getDate();
    let monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let seconds = date.getSeconds();

    if(minutes < 10) minutes =  "0" + minutes;
    if(seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
    const months = ["Styczeń", "Luty", "Marzec", "Kwiecień", "Maj", "Czerwiec", "Lipiec", "Sierpień", "Wrzesień", "Październik", "Listopad", "Grudzień"];
    return `${day} ${months[monthIndex]} ${year} ${hours} : ${minutes} : ${seconds}`; 
}
```

Here is the code responsible for adding editing as well as removing tasks from the todo list and generating the date when adding a task as well as editing it. Now he wants to do so that if the user creates a task for himself, he will normally be added to the list, while if he wants to add the same task to the list of tasks again, he will return a message like "You have already added this task"

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create [mcve]. The question is too broad and needs details.

Comment: So make sure that the new input is not in your list. Without seeing your attempt, we cannot say much more than that.

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create array or something where you store all the added tasks and when you add new task just check whether same task is available inside array or not, if it is available you can show some message to user saying already available.